# How do I add an alert dialog on a onClick method?

Tags: android, mobile, onclick, android-alertdialog

I want to add an alert dialog to have a loading state while a request is executed. Is it possible to do something like:

```
xButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        xButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); 
        alertDialog.setMessage(Please wait);
        alertDialog.show();

        // do some work here
        alertdialog.dismiss

    }
});

        }
        return view;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: u needed the custom dialogue or default dialogue

Comment: You should use AsyncTask and ProgressDialog on this kind of situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any specific reason to use Alert Dialog then you can use Progress Dialog.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    xButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){

                    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(<YourActivityClassName>.this);
                        mProgressDialog.setMessage("message");
                        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        mProgressDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        // Do your work
                        return null;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    };

                }.execute();


}
```

Comment: Hi Naveejr, tried your code and I expierence a crash     06-27 11:35:28.780  30227-30227/com.xxx.xxx E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42deaf08 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1061,288} that was originally added here     any ideeas why? Thank you in advance.P.S- I'm using Android Studio Adrian

Comment: @AdrianAntal  I've modified the code, Try it now and tell me the result.

Comment: some crash occurs:     06-27 13:55:21.934  11382-11382/com.xxx.xxx E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c11da0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1061,288} that was originally added here     Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

use a function to show alert and call it from onclick function.

```
public void showAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                mcontext);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Headding");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("message")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(mcontext.getResources().getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
//                      
                    }
                });
        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: If you are using asynctask, you can call it from preExecute/ postexecute

Answer (score 0):

Hi Adrian giving a simple code hope this helps. good day...

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        alertDialog.setTitle("title");
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.alert_image);
                        alertDialog.setMessage("alert message").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                current_activity.this.finish();
                                Intent inlog=new Intent(current_activity.this,target_activity.class);
                                startActivity(inlog);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
                            {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        AlertDialog alertDialog2=alertDialog.create();
                        alertDialog2.show();
```

Comment: just put it inside onclick or use this inside a function and call it in onClick()

Comment: I added it inside my onClick method,      AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                        alert.setMessage("Please wait...");
                        alert.setCancelable(false);
                        alert.show();

                                //do some work
                        
                        alert.dismiss();     The problem is, it doesn't display it at all. If I take out the     alert.dismiss();     the alert dialog is there, but it stays there. Any thoughts? thank you in advance.

Comment: @AdrianAntal  This alert has two buttons so clicking either one of them the action will take place and the alert will be dismissed .If you need to automatically dismiss the alert after a particular interval you may use a Progressdialog than alertdialog or simply use Toast.

Comment: Hi Wolverine. Thank you for you're reply. The reason I was using an alert dialog was because I don't the user to tap any buttons while the request is processed. Can I do the same thing with a ProgressDialog? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AdrianAntal : You have an answer already for progress dialog :)